# Batch uploading PDF files to ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-python-api

I am trying to upload multiple pdf files to ArcGIS Online content all at once.

Is there is a script that I can use to add content to ArcGIS Online?

Comment: You could look at the bulk upload & publish shp script and modify it for your needs https://gist.github.com/ecaldwell/b48dc1ef6c862414b886

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer in a GeoNet thread named [Python script to Add PDF to My Content](https://community.esri.com/thread/218381-python-script-to-add-pdf-to-my-content).